# SIGBART error when try to debug application

Tags: java, android, jdb, jdwp

I have an android application written in Java. Application works normally but when I try to add it to debug mode using `Attach Debugger to android process`, it crashes with following error :

```
04-16 04:58:28.790 8084-8091/com.abc.dev A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8091 (JDWP)
```

I can not do anything on application. It works normally without debugger attached to process. 
**Device I am using is Motorola E4 plus.**

Can anyone helps in understanding why this might be happening?

Just an update on this one, I tested same app on Nexus 6 and issue is not happening. It appears to be device dependent.